# Сработает ли такой маневр?

Tags: header, ajax, php, javascript

скрипт на javascript через ajax делает запрос на скрипт php, в котором при определенных условиях запускается функция

```
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/auth.php");
```

вопрос: исходная страница, в которой производится такой запрос через аякс, перенаправится ли на /auth.php?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно нет..

Comment: действительно.. что-то я упоролся сегодня..